# Pyspark: How to impute multiple columns in DataFrame in the same action?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Sorry for a similar post but this is a different question on the same code. I'm trying to impute all of these columns:

```
('exact_age','lnght_of_resd','acct_tenure_mnth_nbr','acct_ttce_mnth_nbr','tot_promo_amt', 'tot_rev_amt','int_base_pkg_speed','int_mx_elgbl_speed')
```

With the code below but only the first column is being imputed.  I'm guessing it has to do with the `first()` function.  However, I don't know how to modify the code so it can iterate through all of the columns. When I run this code, `exact_age` is imputed correctly but not the others. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
removeAllDF = df_data.na.drop()
imputeDF = df_data['exact_age','lnght_of_resd','acct_tenure_mnth_nbr','acct_ttce_mnth_nbr','tot_promo_amt','tot_rev_amt','int_base_pkg_speed','int_mx_elgbl_speed']
for x in imputeDF.columns:
    meanValue = removeAllDF.agg(avg(x)).first()[0]
    print(x, meanValue)
    df_data = df_data.na.fill(meanValue, (x))

df_data.show()
```

Comment: This seemed to work when I tried it. Perhaps it is a data issue. What error do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop through each column actually. You can calculate all means at once and do one `df_data.na.fill` call:

```
impute_cols = [
    'exact_age', 'lnght_of_resd', 'acct_tenure_mnth_nbr',
    'acct_ttce_mnth_nbr', 'tot_promo_amt', 'tot_rev_amt',
    'int_base_pkg_speed', 'int_mx_elgbl_speed'
]

mean_df = df_data.na.drop().agg(*[avg(c).alias(c) for c in impute_cols])

df_data = df_data.na.fill(mean_df.first().asDict())
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had modify the last line for it to work for me '''df_data = df_data.na.fill(mean_df.first().asDict()) '''